# Javascript variable setting - list items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this menu and I want to set one variable for each li item, and alert with it's text when clicked. This was easy, I solved for this with the script below.

```
$("ul#menudropd .animal li a").click(function() {
    var whatever = $(this).text();
    alert(whatever); });
```

Now, I also need to include the 'parent' (ie, the text in the mainlinks class) in the alert.  The parent is usually never clicked, only hovered over to display the children.  But, it is text so it should be easy right?

Example:
Currently, you click on "Puppy" and alert says "Puppy".  I need to say "Dog : Puppy". Same for the next section.  Click on "Kitten" I need the alert to come back as "Cat: Kitten".

I know how to have the alert display both once I get that 2nd variable set, I just can't figure out how to do it without clicking it.  Any ideas?

```
<ul id="menudropdown">
<li class="mainlinks"> <a href="#"> Dog </a> 
<div class="animal dog"> 
<li><a href= "#"> Puppy </a></li> 
<li><a href= "#"> Pup </a></li> 
</div>
</li> 
<li class="mainlinks"> <a href="#"> Cat </a> 
<div class="animal cat"> 
<li><a href= "#"> Kitty </a></li> 
<li><a href= "#"> Kitten </a></li> 
</div>
</li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `closest()` and you may also want ul instead of div, the html you have seems invalid as div directly contain li element.

> The HTML List item element `(<li>)` is used to represent a list item. It
>   should be contained in an ordered list (), an unordered list
>   () or a menu (), [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li).

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/my9JX/)

Html

```
<ul id="menudropdown">
    <li class="mainlinks"> <a href="#"> Dog </a> 
        <ul class="animal dog">
            <li><a href="#"> Puppy </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"> Pup </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="mainlinks"> <a href="#"> Cat </a> 
        <ul class="animal cat">
            <li><a href="#"> Kitty </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"> Kitten </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
$("ul#menudropdown .animal li a").click(function () {    
    alert($(this).closest('.mainlinks').find('a:first').text());
});
```

Comment: In case it's not clear from this answer, I think Adil is saying that with your code the browser is automatically adding an `<ul>` element to the HTML hierarchy, then selecting it as the parent of the `<li>` when you wanted to select the `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

You should find the closest li tag with your mainlinks class and then select the text of the first child.
Like this:

```
$(this).child().first().text()+" : "+$(this).text();
```

Comment: Thank you!  I used this in combination with the above answer, much appreciated!